# Failed to perform attach to process operation

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i'm trying to debug a service. when i perform to attach to process via vs 2010 i load the pdb files manually, nevertheless the vs is not attaching to the process, and a hollow break point is shown.
i used the ChkMatch tool to check if the pdb file is matching the exe, attaching you a screenshot of the chkmatch output. [image]

Here is also the moduls window screenshot.
[image]

Any help will be appriciated,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wow i have found the answer. so what you need to do is when you attach to process, in my case c++ .dll make sure that the 'Attach to' code type is set to native and not managed (it will be managed if your code has 3rd party components that were written in c# etc..)